# Wrong size of a MovieClip when set manually

Tags: flash, apache-flex, movieclip

I made a test by adding a MovieClip to a Canvas in Flex.

```
private function onInit():void {
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mc.graphics.clear();
    mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0, 1);
    mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
    mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
    mc.graphics.endFill();
    mainCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(mc);
}

private function onMouseMove():void {
    var child:DisplayObject = mainCanvas.rawChildren.getChildAt(i);
    trace("MovieClip size:", (child as MovieClip).width, (child as MovieClip).height);
}
```

mainCanvas is declared and instanciated in MXML:

```
<Canvas id="mainCanvas" width="400" height="300" />
```

This first attempt works fine and the console displays the following output when I move the mouse over the stage:

```
MovieClip size: 402 302
```

But when I want to explicitly set the size of the movie clip I don't see in anymore and the ouptut display a wrong size.

Here is the update init method:

```
private function onInit():void {
    var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
    mc.width = 400;
    mc.height = 300;
    mc.graphics.clear();
    mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0, 1);
    mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
    mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
    mc.graphics.endFill();
    mainCanvas.rawChildren.addChild(mc);
}
```

And the corresponding output:

```
MovieClip size: 0 0
```

Does someone have any explanation for this strange behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially, you set the size of a empty `MovieClip`:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.width = 400;
mc.height = 300;
```

You are attempting to size a clip with no content.

Set you size after there is content in the clip:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
mc.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0, 1);
mc.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 0.5);
mc.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 300);
mc.graphics.endFill();

mc.width = 400;
mc.height = 300;
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixes my problem although I still don't understand why setting the size when the MovieClip is empty affects the final result.

Comment: `Width` and `height` translate `scaleX` and `scaleY` and with nothing measurable the transformation matrix becomes invalid and your `DisplayObject` will never render content.